# Insert records to Heroku Postgres database using a rails script

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I need to update a dababase from an other database... For this I need to search in existing database if the records exists, if not add... One of the database is locally stored in my computer, and the other one is on heroku... But I don't know how to access heroku database from my computer to create the inserts and to query if I have to insert or not...

Any idea how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect via any DB tool, e.g. Oracle SQL Developer with Postgres JDBC connector, to a Heroku Postgres DB. The parameters are listed in the GUI of postgres.heroku.com for your instance.